# iOS notification sound cut off

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have an app that posts local notifications on iOS 10+ using Swift 4. Everything works properly on my testing and personal devices, however I have some users reporting that the custom notification sound gets cut off after only a second.

I don't know of any setting in the iOS API that would even allow me to control this or how it would happen. The users in question have tried removing and reinstalling the app (in case there is some corrupt sound file somehow) and this doesn't seem to help.

When the device is unlocked, the sound plays fine. This only occurs while the device is locked.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @GJain: Yes, I will add an answer. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this issue was caused by a network race condition.

The application in question works where the server sends a VOIP APNs notification to the device, which will actually wake up the app (as opposed to standard APNs notifications, which don't wake the app).  The app will then post local notification(s) for the information received.  When the user opens the app, it clears all local notifications posted by the app.

I'm not sure when this started happening, but it turns out that when the app was getting woken up by the remote notification, it was running the `ViewDidAppear` function in my initial view controller, even though the app was running in the background and was not launched or visible on the screen.
Code in this function was responsible for clearing the notifications, but only after it checks with the server to ensure that it is allowed to do so.
Hence, we got an odd delay (due to network latency) that would cause the application to clear notifications as soon as they appeared.
This only happens sometimes because the notifications were always scheduled 1 second in the future, so if the network call happened fast enough it had no notifications to clear.

My solution was to put the logic that clears the notifications in the `DidBecomeActive` handler instead of `ViewDidAppear`.  This immediately resolved the issue.